# .c File that "starts" the JVM?

Tags: java, c, jvm

I'm looking at the openjdk source files and I'm wondering where I could find the .c file which is at the root of the Java Virtual Machine. In other words, where/what is the file which contains the `main`? Is there such a thing?

EDIT: I think I'm going to feel dumb in a moment. Is it just the file `java.c`? Because when you type `java classname` into the terminal, that's what's being executed, I guess? Though I can't find anything called `javac.c`, so maybe that's incorrect.

Comment: Use `grep(1)`, or even someting like `cscope(1)` to find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a java.c (source package openjdk-6-src-b27-26_oct_2012.tar.gz).  It's in jdk/src/share/bin/java.c.   According to the code comments, it is the *Shared source for 'java' command line tool.*

Answer (score 2):

If you have the source there's smarter ways to find main.

One dumb way:

```
grep -R main *.c
```

(A little trickier to set up recursive grep right - I'm more used to `git grep`).

Someone more fluent in C can propose better ways...

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the source code from here: http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/
2. Look in the `src/os` folder for the operating system you are interested in, for example `src/os/windows/launcher/java_md.c`